# JS generated DIV problem with keybindings

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My program generates a modal with a carousel inside when a button is clicked.

The images for the carousel are requested from a db, since there can be a different number of images, the divs for the carousel are created dynamical.

The problem occurs when the div is generated on a button click, then keybindings and outside of modal clicks don't work.
There is no problem when the divs are generated during instantiation.

It seems I have a problem with instantiation.

*Shortend Code: http://jsfiddle.net/q7c8v06p/1/*

```js
var imgsrc_array = [];

//x1
function create_modal_layout() {
  imgsrc_array = ["Image/nature.jpg", "Image/snow.jpg", "Image/mountains.jpg"];
  var img_array = new Array(imgsrc_array.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc_array.length; i++) {
    var j = i + 1;
    var img1 = document.createElement("IMG");
    img1.setAttribute("src", imgsrc_array[i]);
    img1.setAttribute("alt", "Nr. " + i);
    img1.setAttribute("onclick", "currentDiv(" + j + ")");
    img1.setAttribute("class", "demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off r_selection");
    img1.setAttribute("style", "width: 100%");
    img_array[i] = img1;
  }
  
  //sets % per element
  var a = Math.floor(100 / imgsrc_array.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc_array.length; i++) {
    var div0 = document.createElement("DIV");
    if (i === 0) {
      div0.setAttribute("class", "w3-col top_img1");
      div0.setAttribute("style", "width:20%;height:30%");
    } else {
      div0.setAttribute("class", "w3-col");
      div0.setAttribute("style", "width:" + a + "%;height:30%");
    }
    div0.appendChild(img_array[i]);
    document.getElementById("imagetest0").appendChild(div0);
  }
  //x1
}
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//modal functions

function openModal(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
  //alert(document.getElementById('hidden2').value)
}

function closeModal(id1) {
  document.getElementById(id1).style.display = "none";
  //alert(document.getElementById('hidden2').value)
  if (id1 === "id01")
    $("#imagetest0").empty();
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  //alert("plus "+n);
  showDivs(+slideIndex + n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  //alert("current "+n);
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  //alert("show "+n);
  slideIndex = n;
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(
      " w3-opacity-off r_test", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-opacity-off r_test";
  document.getElementById("hidden1").value = x[slideIndex - 1].alt;
  document.getElementById("hidden2").value = slideIndex;
}

function openModal2(i) {

  document.getElementById('extra1').src = imgsrc_array[i];
  document.getElementById('id02').style.display = "block";
}

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//z1
//key binding
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').keyup(function(event) {

    var key = event.keyCode;

    if (key === 37) //left arrow
    {
      plusDivs(-1);
    } else if (key === 39) //right arrow
    {
      plusDivs(1);
    } else if (key === 27) //esc
    {
      if (document.getElementById('id02').style.display === 'block') {
        closeModal('id02');
      } else if (document.getElementById('id01').style.display === 'block') {
        closeModal('id01');
      }
    } else if (key === 13) //enter
    {
      if (document.getElementById('id02').style.display === 'block') {} else if (document.getElementById('id01').style.display === 'block')
        ajax_call1('but1');
    } else if (key === 32) //space
    {
      if (document.getElementById('id01').style.display === 'block')
        openModal2(document.getElementById("hidden2").value - 1);
    }
  })
});

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// z1
//click outside of modal to esc

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('id02');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  } else if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}

.frame {
  width: 60%;
  height: 92%;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  background: #938c8c;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.frame2 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 92%;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

.modal_buttons {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.r_selection {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.r_selection:hover {
  border-color: #78FF33;
  /*green */
}

.set_height {
  top: 67%;
}

.r_test {
  border-color: #FFDD43;
  /* red */
}

.extra_info {
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<input type="hidden" name="hidden_field1" id="hidden1" value="HIDDEN FIELD">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_field2" id="hidden2" value=1>
<div class="w3-container">
  <!--x1-->
  <button onclick="create_modal_layout();openModal('id01');currentDiv(document.getElementById('hidden2').value)" id="but1" class="w3-hover-shadow">Open
  </button>
  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal w3-card-4 ">
    <span class="w3-text-white w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey w3-container w3-display-topright" onclick="closeModal('id01')" style="cursor: pointer">×</span>
    <div class="frame" id="frame1">
      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 1200px">
          <h1>
            <center>
              <span id="result_test">Umgebung</span>
            </center>
          </h1>
          <div class="w3-row w3-center w3-black">
            <span class="w3-display-left w3-btn w3-light-grey set_height" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</span>
            <span class="w3-display-right w3-btn w3-light-grey set_height" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</span>
            <div id=imagetest0 style="height:80px">
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="mySlides" src="Image/nature.jpg" onclick="openModal2(0)" style="width: 100%" alt="Nr 1">
          <img class="mySlides" src="Image/snow.jpg" onclick="openModal2(1)" style="width: 100%" alt="Nr 2">
          <img class="mySlides" src="Image/mountains.jpg" onclick="openModal2(2)" style="width: 100%" alt="Nr 3">
          <div id="id02" class="w3-modal w3-card-4 ">
            <span class="w3-text-white w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey w3-container w3-display-topright" onclick="closeModal('id02')" style="cursor: pointer">×</span>
            <div class="frame2">
              <div class="w3-modal-content">
                <img class="extra_info" id="extra1" alt="Extra">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="w3-button w3-left w3-border w3-red modal_buttons" onclick="closeModal('id01')">Close</button>
        <button class="w3-button w3-green w3-right w3-border modal_buttons">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In code:**
  x1:  in html window: is button click function

              x1: in js window: is function
z1: in js window: keybindings and click out of modal event

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: instead of using img1.setAttribute("onclick"...) have you tried adding an event listener? such as img1.addEventListener("click", <your function>)

Comment: img1.setAttribute("onclick"...)  is working so I don't see the point?

Comment: sorry, i dont know what your actual problem is, which "div" is your problem? maybe it has something to do with event bubbling/capturing...

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with  instantiation.
Had to generate the divs before the load to be found.